# Showing $E_4(z)$ and $E_6(z)$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: modular-forms, modular-function

Let

$E_4(z)= - \frac{B_4}{8}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_3(n) q^n$

and

$E_6(z)= - \frac{B_6}{12}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_5(n) q^n$

How does one show they are algebraically independant over $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: We have a product formula for $ \Delta=\frac{ E_4^3-27 E_6^2}{1728} \in S_{12}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ and it has a simple zero at $i\infty$ thus $f \mapsto \frac{f}{ \Delta}$ is an isomorphism  $S_{k+12}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z})) \to M_{k}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$. Then we show $\mathbb{C}[E_4,E_6]$ contains $M_{k}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z})) , k < 12$ obtaining that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, M_{k}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))  \subset \mathbb{C}[E_4,E_6]$. What next ? @mdave16

Comment: @mdave16 yes I do know the valence formula.

Comment: I also know that $M_k$ is spanned by $E_4^j E_b^l$  with $4j+6l=k$. Does that Help? @mdave16

Comment: I misunderstood, I did Lin ind, instead of alg ind., yep, just refreshed, ignore anything I said.

Comment: This is the valence formula ! And I meant $\Delta = \frac{1}{1728} (E_4^3-E_6^2)$ but it is the same.  Algebraically independent means $E_6 \not \in \overline{\mathbb{C}(E_4)}$. A related fact should be that $j_N$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}(j)$ (the function field of the modular curve of $\Gamma(N)$)

Comment: @reuns,   thanks for your help. Someone answered me on math over flow. Here is the link :  
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282554/eisenstein-series-e-4z-and-e-6z-algebraically-independent-over-mathbb

Comment: Is it a common property of graded rings/algebras ?